# matplotlib conditional formatting labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an horizontal barchart in which I am setting the labels with the command:

```
ax.set_yticklabels(df_chart.country_group)
```

I need some of the labels to be bold (and if possible aligned center-ly) depending on some name of the label.

I have tried with:

```
ax.set_yticklabels(df_chart.country_group, weight=["bold", "bold", "normal"...])
```

but the function does not accept a list.
I have tries also with a loop:

```
for label in ax.get_yticklabels():
     if label in ["World", "Developing countries", "Developed countries"]:
         label.set_fontproperties(weight="bold")
```

but I was not able to extract the label value from the Text object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you cannot use a list for such font properties. The second approach goes in the right direction. You need to `get_text()` from the labels to compare with some other string.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([1,3,12])
ax.set_yticks([1,3,7,11])
ax.set_yticklabels(list("ABCD"))

for label in ax.get_yticklabels():
    if label.get_text() in ["B","C"]:
        label.set_weight("bold")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that this only works if, as in this case, the label text has been set previously via `set_*ticklabels`.